# How can I create a .NET Assembly that can be called from Microsoft Access? (At a complete loss)

Tags: c#, vba, visual-studio, com-interop

I am building a Class Libray using the .NET Framework 4.8 in C# with Visual Studio 2019.

I want to call functions in my .NET Class Library from Access 2016 VBA.

When I try to call the function from VBA, I get the following error:

```
Run-time error '-2147024894 (800700002)':

Automation error
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

- The Reference for the Custom Class Library has been added in VBA under `Tools | References`.
- The C# assembly is built using the `Copy Local` option on each referenced assembly.
- I tried a `SFC /SCANNOW` from an Administrator:Command Prompt. This reported that some DLLs were replaced.  A follow up run of `SFC /SCANNOW` reported that no issues were found.
- The referenced assemblies are all Microsoft .NET Framework 4.8 assemblies.  There are no third-party DLLs involved.
- There are no errors or warnings that occur during the Build.
- The assembly is marked as `COM Visible`.
- The assembly was successfully registered with `regasm`.

A have tried a few additional approaches. No success yet.

- I restarted from scratch - and created a .NET Framework 4.72 DLL.
- The Assembly Information has 'Make assembly COM-Visible'checked.
- The Build Information has 'Register for COM Interop' checked.
- I successfully added the references to the Tools | References in the VBA Editor.

Now I get the following error:

```
Run-time error 429 activex component can't create object.
```

The code for the class is below:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace NWBLibrary
{
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)]
    public class ReedDecibelLogger
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// GetSha256FileHash computes a SHA256 hash of a file.
        /// </summary>
        
        public string GetSha256FileHash(string fileSpec)
        {
            string fileHash = string.Empty;
            byte[] hashValue;

            SHA256 managedSha256 = SHA256.Create();

            FileStream fileStream;
            using (fileStream = new FileStream(fileSpec, FileMode.Open))
            {
                hashValue = managedSha256.ComputeHash(fileStream);
                fileStream.Close();
            }

            fileHash = Convert.ToBase64String(hashValue);
            return fileHash;
        }

    }
}
```

The reference for the assembly above has been added to the `Tools | References` section of the VBA editor.

[image: VBA References for .NET Class Library.]

The VBA Code is:

```
' Returns the SHA256 near unique hash for the specified file.
Public Function filehash(ByVal fileSpec As String) As String

   Dim loggerObj As New NWBLibrary.ReedDecibelLogger

   filehash = loggerObj.GetSha256FileHash(fileSpec)

End Function
```

My questions are:

1. Where should .NET assemblies (both custom and references) be located so that VBA can find all required DLLs?
2. Do I need to modify search paths on my development boxes so that Access VBA can find the DLLs?
3. Is this an assembly the the Microsoft assemblies depend upon that are not included when `Copy Local` is used?
4. Should I use the Fusion Log Viewer (fuslogvw.exe) to see if a dependent assembly is missing?
5. Could someone recommend a reference or third-party book that discusses building libraries for use with VBA?
6. If this is a problem of the CLR not seeing all dependencies, how would you make the GAC and all dependencies visible to the CLR?
7. Are additional steps required so that VBA can see the assemblies and GAC?List item?
8. Do I need to create a DLL entry point for the C# Assembly?
9. Do I need to try a different version of Microsoft Access?
10. I can get this to run on one workstation but it fails with the 429 error on another workstation.  This is probably a dependency issue.

I am using the Fusion Logger to see if a dependency is missing on the machine that throws the 429 error.

Comment: You are developing a .NET COM object, aren't you? Is it registered for COM using regasm?

Comment: Yes - sorry I should have said that - the library is marked as COM Visible.  I also used regasm to successfully register the assembly.  I have added these bullets to the main post.

Comment: Have you tried  `regasm ... /codebase`? fuslogvw.exe is certainly a good idea. You can also use the ProcMon tool from sysinternals, filter per your process name, registry and file access, see what is looked for.

Comment: The assembly you register with regasm is easily found by the CLR, but any of its dependencies are not.  The CLR does *not* look in the same directory, just the GAC and the .exe path like it normally does.  That makes /codebase a pain, one reason it is not the default.  Consider the GAC, ILMerge to make a single DLL, or AppDomain.AssemblyResolve if you have a main interface that's always created first.

Comment: Good feedback!  I will try these.